# How to show Bitmap in Razor cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor, bitmap

I'm receiving an list of objects from a model with 6 properties that I need to show in a table in cshtml, one property of these objects are System.Drawing.Bitmap type which is generated at runtime.

is there a way to show this Bitmap object with Razor in the cshtml? Thanks everyone!

```
 @model List<Database.DisplayPiece>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_VisualRuleLayout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <h3>@ViewBag.title</h3>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Branch #</th>
                <th>Lot</th>
                <th>Last Ordered</th>
                <th>Width (inches)</th>
                <th>Length (feet)</th>
                <th>Available</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var available in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => available.Branch)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => available.LotName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => available.OrderDate)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => available.Width)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => available.Length)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => available.Bitmap)</td>
                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the `Bitmap` property? A byte array? A URL as a string? A file path?

Comment: I'm receiving it as a Bitmap object from a model at runtime. Once I run the program, it is showing the table with all the Bitmap object properties in the field that I'm specifying in the Html. thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

before sending the list of "DisplayPiece" objects which contain the bitmap object inside it, it is necessary to convert the Bitmap to Bytes[]
with the following:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        YOUR_BITMAP_OBJECT.Save(stream, stem.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        stream.Close();
        byteArray = stream.ToArray();
    }
```

after the objects are converted to Byte[], create a new model to save the objects with the Bitmap attributes converted to Byte[] and send it to the view.

View:

In the line where you need to display the bitmap object, you paste the following:

```
<td>
@{var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(available.Bitmap);
var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
}
<img src="@imgSrc"/>
</td>
```